# regular expression replace word in camelWords

Tags: sed, regular-expression, perl

I want to replace a word in camelWords like:
to replace "foo" with "bar" in text:

```
ifootest // not replace this foo
Ifootest // not replace this foo
IfooTest // << replace this foo
I foo Test // << replace this foo
I_foo_Test // << replace this foo
```

or to replace "Foo" with "Bar" in text:

```
IFootest // not replace
IFooTest // not replace
iFooTest // replace
i Foo Test //replace
I_Foo_Test // replace
```

the rule is:
if I intput a word.

the character before the first character of the word should not be the same case of the the first character of the word.

the character after the last character of the word should not be the same case of the the last character of the word.

Comment: Then why you replace the last line of the second list of examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
perl -pe 's/(?<![[:lower:]])foo(?![[:lower:]])/bar/g'
```

That is replace `foo` instances that are neither preceded nor followed by a lowercase letter using the negative look-behind and look-ahead operators.

That works with ASCII text only. Do work with your locale's charset, you can add a `-Mopen=locale` option. Or use `-C` to work with UTF-8 text.

That would need to be adapted for words like `Foo`/`foO`/`FoO` where the first or last character is an uppercase letter.

To make it work for arbitrary words, you could do something like:

```
WORD=FoO REPL=bar perl  -pe 's{
  (?(?=[[:lower:]])      # if following character is lowercase
      (?<![[:lower:]])|  # preceding must not be lower 
      (?<![[:upper:]])   # otherwise preceding must not be upper
  ) \Q$ENV{WORD}\E
  (?(?<=[[:lower:]])     # if preceding character is lowercase
      (?![[:lower:]])|   # following must not be lower 
      (?![[:upper:]])    # otherwise following must not be upper
  )}{$ENV{REPL}}gx'
```

Comment: hello thank you, I use it every day, but in some siuation like `I "Foo"`, I want to replace the Foo with bar in this way, it does not work.

Comment: @JohnChen, you mean that `echo 'I "Foo"' | perl -pe 's/(?<![[:upper:]])Foo(?![[:lower:]])/bar/g'` doesn't output `I "bar"`? I can't reproduce. It works for me. Same for the second approach with `WORD=Foo`

Answer (score 0):

This is probably about 1,000,000 times slower than the `perl` but here's an `awk` version just for the challenge of it. But anyway

```
awk -v gzin="Foo" -v gzout="Bar" '
  BEGIN {FS=gzin;
    cb=(substr(gzin,1,1)~/[a-z]/)?"[a-z]$":"[A-Z]$"
    ca=(substr(gzin,length(gzin)-1,1)~/[a-z]/)?"^[a-z]":"^[A-Z]"
  }
  {printf $1; for (f=2; f<=NF; f++) printf ("%s%s", ((($(f-1) ~ cb) || ( $(f) ~ ca ))?gzin:gzout), $f) ; 
  print ""}' file
```

And it even matches the comments

```
ifootest // not replace this foo
Ifootest // not replace this foo
IbarTest // << replace this bar
I bar Test // << replace this bar
I_bar_Test // << replace this bar
```

and with `-v gzin="Foo" -v gzout="Bar"`

```
IFootest // not replace
IFooTest // not replace
iBarTest // replace
i Bar Test //replace
I_Bar_Test // replace
```

**Walkthrough**

```
awk -v gzin="Foo" -v gzout="Bar" '
```

Load your match `gzin` and replacement `gzout` as variables

```
  BEGIN {FS=gzin;
```

Split on `gzin`

```
    cb=(substr(gzin,1,1)~/[a-z]/)?"[a-z]$":"[A-Z]$"
```

Test the case of the first character of `gzin` and set up a regex to match it

```
    ca=(substr(gzin,length(gzin)-1,1)~/[a-z]/)?"^[a-z]":"^[A-Z]"
```

Ditto the last character

```
  }
  {printf $1; for (f=2; f<=NF; f++) printf ("%s%s", ((($(f-1) ~ cb) || ( $(f) ~ ca ))?gzin:gzout), $f) ;
```

Iterate over the fields testing the previous and current fields and put the appropriate value between them

```
  print ""}' file
```

End each line

**PS** I think I hurt my brain